# Does attacking a ring of flowers make it disappear faster?

Tags: vampire-survivors

In the Mad Forest, sometimes a ring of flower enemies will appear around me. They slowly get closer until they all suddenly disappear after a little while. Does attacking a ring of flower enemies make them disappear faster? Or do you just have to wait for them to disappear on their own?

[image: Ring of flowers]

Answer (score 2):

Each flower is a individual enemy with slow speed and high health. By focusing fire on just a few, you can create an opening.

If you're having trouble while inside the ring though, I would recommend instead just walking out and tanking the small hit to health.

Comment: So the flowers disappear after a predetermined amount of time then?

Comment: @Stevoisiak if you haven't killed them all, yes